# How to check cursor null or not in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to check values of field `ID` in `BangCauHoi` table.
This is my function:

```
public boolean checkID(String ndCauHoi){
        boolean check = true;
        String query = "select ID from BangCauHoi where CauHoi=?";
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, new String[] { ndCauHoi });
        if (c != null)
        {
             c.moveToFirst();
                 if (c.isNull(c.getColumnIndex("ID")))
                 {
                     check = false;
                 }
        }
         c.close();
    return check;
}
```

And result:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{us.datn_02/us.datn_02.ShowQuestion}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Somebody can help me please?

if I change my code to:

```
public boolean checkID(String ndCauHoi){
        boolean check = true;
        String query = "select ID from BangCauHoi where CauHoi=?";
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, new String[] { ndCauHoi });
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
                 if (c.isNull(c.getColumnIndex("ID")))
                 {
                     check = false;
                 }
        }
         c.close();
    return check;
}
```

then it always return `true` even field `ID` have no value with this `where` clause.

Help me please!...
Sorry because my english.

Comment: are you sure about the column name ?

Comment: use c.getCount() to know length of data coming from cursor

Comment: if you are not sure about your Cursor content, use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(Cursor)` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check to see whether or not it is empty with the following statement:

```
if (c.moveTofirst() && c.getCount > 0)
```

or

```
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst())
```

As to why it is empty, I would guess that you have mistyped a statement somewhere. I always use the `query` [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) in the `SQLiteDatabase` class instead of `rawQuery`, and use constants for my column names instead of hardcoding them to try and avoid these problems.

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="BangCauHoi";
public static final String CAUHOI = "CauHoi";

Cursor c = yourDatabaseInstance.getReadabledatabase().query(
    YourDatabaseName.TABLE_NAME, 
    new String[] { YourDatabaseName.KEY_ID },
    YourDatabaseName.CAUHOI + "=?", 
    new String[] { ndCauHoi }, 
    null, null, null);
```

Comment: and your Cursor can return null??

Answer (score 2):

Your database does not have any rows mathing the selection and `moveToFirst()` returns false. When unchecked, you'll get the exception about trying to retrieve values from a nonexisting row. When checked, it returns the default value `true` you've specified.