# Android SQLite Check If Record Exists Doesn't Work

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm checking if a sqlLite table record is available or not , it's giving me that the record is available even if it's not

```
public void checkIfExcist(Context mCtx, String recordName, String ValueCheck) {

    DatabaseHelper mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    SQLiteDatabase mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SQLITE_TABLE
            + " WHERE " + recordName + " ='" + ValueCheck + "'", null);

    if (mCursor != null) {

        Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Available", 3000).show();
        /* record exist */
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Not Available", 3000).show();
        /* record not exist */
    }

}
```

Comment: an empty result set is still a valid result that just happens to have no rows... don't check if the cursor exists, check if there's any rows in the result set.

Comment: I understood you , could you help me with the sql query ?

Comment: The query remains unchanged. Is the condition you have to change.

Comment: You mean I check mCursor => 0 ? @DerGolem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rawQuery` will always return a `cursor`, even if it is empty (which is different to `null`). This is why it will always pass your `null` check.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623524/how-to-check-cursor-null-or-not-in-android/29624393#29624393) should answer your question.

Comment: @YahyaZakariya Glad to hear it - please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the cursor nullity, check if the record count is greater than 0.
In other words, change this

```
if (mCursor != null) {
```

to this

```
if(mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
```